# jQuery multiple selectors into dynamic attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to attach an event to a separate onhover trigger. But I am having problems using multiple selectors since its dynamic.

Need help ::: Upon hovering on the yellow box named 'Rings', this should trigger the animated slide event for the green box above it.

```
$('.boxgrid1').hover(function(){  
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:300});  
}, function() {  
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'247px'},{queue:false,duration:300});  
});
```

Comment: nice design, one question do you mean the same effect that appears on hover the green, and you also want the yellow region to activate it?

Comment: What exactly do you want answered here? Do you want help to bid events to your images "Rings", "earrings" etc and that should trigger an animate?

Comment: Given the structure of your HTML you may have to use some of jQuery's DOM traversal functions to accomplish that. You may also want to add a common class to each of your images so that you can select them all and animate them using a single `hover()` binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a few markup tweaks we can *greatly* simplify your code, for example let's give those hover `<div>` elements a common class as well, like this:

```
<div class="boxgrid boxgrid1">
```

Then your code becomes *much* simpler, you can replace all that repeated code with this:

```
$('.boxgrid .cover').css({ top: '247px' });

$('.boxgrid').hover(function() {
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({ top: '0px' }, 300);
}, function() {
    $(".cover", this).stop().animate({ top: '247px' }, 300);
});
$("#shop_buttons_table tr:nth-child(2)").delegate("td", "mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
    $("#shop_buttons_table tr:nth-child(1) .boxgrid").eq($(this).index()).trigger(e);
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Da8xH/), all we're doing is taking the "hover" events from the lower cells and passing them onto the `.boxgrid` elements in the row before, the net effect (with the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) calls you already had) is a single hoverable area for the user.

Comment: Thanks! It is very helpful to see and understand the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Give a class name to your `<a>` tag outside `<img>`(RINGS) tag like `<a class="boxgrid1" href="#">`